# Converting Athena output to strongly typed model in Go

Tags: go, amazon-athena

Is there an easy way to convert from `athena.GetQueryResultsOutput` struct to a user-defined struct in Go?

Here's a snippet of what I want to achieve:

```
const testSql = `
select
    id,
    name,
    count(source_id) as aggregate_count,
    array_agg(source_id) as aggregate_source_ids,
    array_agg(source_name) as aggregate_source_names
from my_glue_catalog_table
group by id, name
`

type myModel struct {
    id                   int64
    name                 string
    aggregateCount       int
    aggregateSourceIDs   []int64
    aggregateSourceNames []string
}

queryResultOutput, err = awsAthenaClient.GetQueryResults(ctx, &queryResultInput)
// var mapped []myModel = mapper.FromGetQueryResultsOutput(queryResultOutput.ResultSet)
```

And here's the structure of `queryResultOutput.ResultSet`:

```
ResultSet: {
    ResultSetMetadata: {
      ColumnInfo: [
        {
          CaseSensitive: false,
          CatalogName: "hive",
          Label: "id",
          Name: "id",
          Nullable: "UNKNOWN",
          Precision: 10,
          Scale: 0,
          SchemaName: "",
          TableName: "",
          Type: "integer"
        },
        {
          CaseSensitive: true,
          CatalogName: "hive",
          Label: "name",
          Name: "name",
          Nullable: "UNKNOWN",
          Precision: 2147483647,
          Scale: 0,
          SchemaName: "",
          TableName: "",
          Type: "varchar"
        },
        {
          CaseSensitive: false,
          CatalogName: "hive",
          Label: "aggregate_count",
          Name: "aggregate_count",
          Nullable: "UNKNOWN",
          Precision: 19,
          Scale: 0,
          SchemaName: "",
          TableName: "",
          Type: "bigint"
        },
        {
          CaseSensitive: false,
          CatalogName: "hive",
          Label: "aggregate_source_ids",
          Name: "aggregate_source_ids",
          Nullable: "UNKNOWN",
          Precision: 0,
          Scale: 0,
          SchemaName: "",
          TableName: "",
          Type: "array"
        },
        {
          CaseSensitive: false,
          CatalogName: "hive",
          Label: "aggregate_source_names",
          Name: "aggregate_source_names",
          Nullable: "UNKNOWN",
          Precision: 0,
          Scale: 0,
          SchemaName: "",
          TableName: "",
          Type: "array"
        }
      ]
    },
    Rows: [{
        // first row data (from page 1 of results) is header, we can ignore this
        Data: [
            VarCharValue: "id" },
            VarCharValue: "name" },
            VarCharValue: "aggregate_count" },
            VarCharValue: "aggregate_source_ids" },
            VarCharValue: "aggregate_source_names" }
        ]
      },
      // all subsequent rows are data values:
      {
        Data: [
            VarCharValue: "920000" },
            VarCharValue: "mydata1" },
            VarCharValue: "2" },
            VarCharValue: "[52800, 113000]" },
            VarCharValue: "[sourcedata1, sourcedata2]" }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

Full code example I've written: [gist](https://gist.github.com/kent-id/4460135d6313b1e45c556ce2cd2af2c9)

If there's no better alternative, I'm thinking to write a converter package like the following. The main caveat will be converting arrays reliably though as one of the string values in the array might contain a comma. And I believe we can only return as `[]interface{}` because Go doesn't support generics (as of today)?

```
// myModel defines a schema that corresponds with testSql above
type myModel struct {
    id                   int      `athenaconv:"id"`
    name                 string   `athenaconv:"name"`
    aggregateCount       int64    `athenaconv:"aggregate_count"`
    aggregateSourceIDs   []int64  `athenaconv:"aggregate_source_ids"`
    aggregateSourceNames []string `athenaconv:"aggregate_source_names"`
}
mapper := athenaconv.MapperFor(reflect.TypeOf(myModel))
var mapped []interface{} = mapper.FromAthenaResultSet(queryResultOutput.ResultSet)
```

Comment: please rewrite to introduce first the Athena API, the current result you get, the desired result, then describe the gap difficulty.

Comment: @mh-cbon I guess I was hoping for an easier alternative around converting Athena [ResultSet](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/service/athena/types/types.go#L460), which is basically a 2D array of string + separate metadata info, to a strongly-typed model in golang. I ended up creating my own package to achieve this using reflection.

Answer (score 1):

As I couldn't find better alternative and I work with lots of data sets to analyze, I wrote my own package library to figure out the column mapping and convert from [athena types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html) to go data types. This will help us bind athena `ResultSet` to slice of strongly-typed model.

I made it open-source under [athenaconv](https://github.com/kent-id/athenaconv). Leaving as answer in case it helps someone else.

**Go get it**

```bash
go get github.com/kent-id/athenaconv
```

**Usage**

```golang
mapper, err := athenaconv.NewMapperFor(reflect.TypeOf(MyModel{}))
if err != nil {
    handleError(err)
}

var mapped []interface{}
mapped, err = mapper.FromAthenaResultSetV2(ctx, queryResultOutput.ResultSet)
if err != nil {
    handleError(err)
}
for _, mappedItem := range mapped {
    mappedItemModel := mappedItem.(*MyModel)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *mappedItemModel)
}
```

Comment: avoid yourself useless alloc https://github.com/kent-id/athenaconv/blob/main/mapper.go#L59 at and make use of the length available from the slice of rows https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/blob/main/service/athena/types/types.go#L460

Comment: @mh-cbon - yes you are right I'll get the useless alloc removed. If you have more feedback, please let me know either through GitHub issue suggestion/DM. I'm at early stage of diving into golang world so really appreciate your feedback :)